# Something broke in my PHP - Twilio API

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I think it's a small syntax error somewhere as it did used to work fine. When I send for example "to do description, 12-01-14 12:00" which is the correct format, it goes to the database fine but the response text is never send. However if I send "example, " then i get a response. The Help text response works fine when that is triggered.
Could someone help?

*i've removed some parts of the responses for privacy reasons*

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

    mysql_connect("**", "**", "**");
    mysql_select_db("**");

    $description = $_REQUEST['Body'];

    if($description == 'Helpme') { 
        $help = "To-Do Description, DD-MM-YY HH:MM";
        ?>
            <Response><SMS><?php echo $help; ?></SMS></Response>
        <?php
        exit;
    };

    $new = str_split($description);

    $bool = false; 
    $date = '';

    foreach($new as &$value) {
        if($value == ',') {
            $bool = true;
        }
        if($bool == false){
            $descrip .= $value;
        }
        if ($bool == true) {
            $date .= $value;
        }
    };

    if($date[0] == ',' && $date[1] == ' ') {
        $date = ltrim($date, ", ");
    } elseif($date[0] == ',') {
        $date = ltrim($date, ",");
    };
    $date .= ":00";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO notes (NoteDesc, NoteTime) VALUES ('$descrip', '$date')");
    ?>
        <Response>
          <SMS><?php echo "You've added $descrip to your to-do-list. You will be reminded at $date."; ?></SMS>
        </Response>
```

Comment: If this "isn't working" it's likely that there will be a message in your server error log that explains why, and gives the line that the problem occurred in. What is that message? It's too much to expect people to wade through your code looking for an unspecified error in an unspecified place.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment - but it's a bit long.

> I think it's a small syntax error somewhere

As Mike W says, if there's a syntactic error then PHP will generate an error message - if you don't know if/how/where it's logged then you have 3 problems you urgently need to solve before you start asking questions here.

If you don't know how to test a bit code for syntax errors then you have a fourth problem.

> used to work fine

and have you compared this version the one you checked into your version control system when it passed testing previously? If you don't have a version control system then you have a fifth problem.

How are you testing it? If you don't have test cases written and known to work with a previous version then you have a sixth problem.